# Android trying to use Preferences to save data

Tags: android, save, android-preferences

I’m trying to learn how `Preferences` work by writing a short program to store `ted` in the key `board` and then load the value in `boardstr`.
When I use `getString` to load the value, the value of `boardstr` does not change.

```
boardstr= new String();      
boardstr="fred";
// set the prefrence to ted
this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("board","ted");
// kload the prfrence in boardstr
this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getString("board",boardstr);
// boardstr stil equals fred, not ted
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to either [`commit()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29) or [`apply()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29) the changes in order for them to be saved and take effect.

E.g.:

```
// set the prefrence to ted
this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("board","ted");
this.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().apply();
```